# JSON Data to Table using NodeJs Express.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, express

Good Day!

I'm new to NodeJs Express.js

how can i convert this data to nodejs, i need to calculate the data and display it on a table  with loops? Any Tips for me guys?

here is the json data

`{"652":
    {"employee_info":
            {"employee_name":""},
        "date_log":
            {
                "2017-12-31":
                {
                    "config":{"shift":"R","hours_per_day":8,"break_hours":1,"flexi_hours":0,"grace_period":15},
                    "log":{"time_in":"2017-12-31 07:35:37","time_out":"2017-12-31 09:34:01","break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],"break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],"shift_in":"2017-12-31 16:00:00","shift_out":"2017-12-31 16:00:00","status":"present","holiday":"no","overtime":"no"}
                },
                "2017-12-29":
                    {
                        "config":{"shift":"FL","hours_per_day":8,"break_hours":1,"flexi_hours":2,"grace_period":0},
                        "log":{"time_in":"2017-12-29 00:20:00","time_out":"2017-12-29 10:35:00","break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],"break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],"shift_in":"2017-12-29 16:00:00","shift_out":"2017-12-29 16:00:00","status":"present","holiday":"no","overtime":"no"
                    }
                },
                "2017-12-28":
                    {
                        "config":{"shift":"R","hours_per_day":8,"break_hours":1,"flexi_hours":0,"grace_period":0},
                        "log":{"time_in":"2017-12-28 00:02:25","time_out":"2017-12-29 10:35:00","break_out":["2017-12-31 12:00:00"],"break_in":["2017-12-31 13:00:00"],"shift_in":"2017-12-28 16:00:00","shift_out":"2017-12-28 16:00:00","status":"present","holiday":"no","overtime":"no"}}
                    }
                }
}`

Comment: "convert data to nodejs"? you mean parse the json as is using nodejs or convert it to array?

Comment: You cannot convert the data to nodejs. I believe what you are expecting is to parse this json data into a javascript object. You can do that with `const obj = JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use JSON.parse:

for example if you want to access the employee_name field you can do something like :

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.employee_info.employee_name);
```